# Create user independent logfiles in C:\ProgramData

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, permissions

I would like to create logfiles for my application in an user independent lactation. AFAIK `C:\ProgramData` is good place for that.

I've tried it this way:

```
if not DirectoryExists('C:\ProgramData\MyApp') then
    CreateDirectory('C:\ProgramData\MyApp', nil);

LogFileStream := TFileStream.Create('C:\ProgramData\MyApp\LogFile01.txt', fmCreate, (fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone));
```

The problem with this approach is that the created filed does not have `Authenticated Users` nor `Everyone` in `Properties->Security->Group or user names`.

This results in other users being unable to modify the created files.

But how can I achieve this, also other users being albe to modify the created files.

I think it must be possible to have files with this permission there. Some files do have this permission e.g. `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Ringtones\Ringtone *.wav`

Maybe either in

1.) somehow creating a 'MyApp' folder in `C:\ProgramData` with `Authenticated Users` or `Everyone` permission which would result in `TFileStream` automatically creating files with the same permission or

2.) somehow telling `TFileStream` to create the files with the required permission or

3.) somehow changing the files permission with some API function after its creation or

4.) some other way??

Comment: Do not use hard coded `'C:\ProgramData'`. Use Windows API to retrieve  this path (FOLDERID_ProgramData/CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA)

Answer (score 2):

The default permissions in `C:\ProgramData`, aka `FOLDERID_ProgramData` allow any user to create new files and folders. However, only the user who creates the file or folder has permission to write to it.

So, if you wish to allow any user to modify objects under `FOLDERID_ProgramData` then you need to add a permissive ACL to grant those rights. You would typically do that when you installed your program. Create a folder under `FOLDERID_ProgramData` and add an ACL to grant rights to whichever class of users you wish to allow full access.

As an aside, clearly you should not be hard coding `C:\ProgramData`, but instead using `FOLDERID_ProgramData` with the known folder API. I guess the code in the question is just for testing, and your real program code does it correctly.

Comment: The nature of logfiles is normaly that they are created during runtime and not during installation. So how couldI change the permission programmatically?

Comment: I wasn't clear. I've edited. At install time you create a folder under `FOLDERID_ProgramData` and add the ACL to that folder. Then the objects in that folder inherit the rights of the folder.

Comment: Okay I got that. Also that using `FOLDERID_ProgramData` is better than using hardcoded `C:\ProgramData`. But since my app has no real installer for several historical reasons it would have to create and change the permission of the folder by itself. Which API function would I have to use to achieve this?

Comment: You'll need admin rights to do that I believe. So you want that in a separate program, or at least your program restarted with runas verb and command line args. Really, an installer is the best way to do this. But if you really want to know how to apply an ACL to a directory, search on SO for questions on that topic. It has been asked and answered many many times before.

Comment: Create the folder using `CreateDirectory()`, providing a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` that points to a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` containing the desired ACLs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: admin rights shouldn't be necessary, so long as you make the change as soon as the folder is created (since at that point you're still running as the user who gets access by default).  Or, as Remy suggests, set the permissions at the same time as creating the directory.

Comment: there still is a gotcha - if first run of program is made using UAC elevation - from the installer for example - then the log file is created with admins-only rights and can not be modified by mere users no matter what the parent folder's ACL was. Second page of the forum has the unit to create file with permissions at http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-374131/0.html#st_15_view_0